# Area inside square

Tags: geometry

Let ABCD be a square of side length 3. P is a point interior of this square such that each the the angles APB, BPC, CPD and DPA are at least 60 degrees. Find the area of the region where P could lie?

I have tried doing construction whereby creating 4 equilateral triangles on the sides of the square and finding the common intersection area inside didn’t give me the desired answer. Appreciate any smart ideas or solution at hand.

Comment: The border of the area you are looking for consists of circular arcs. Take a look at [the inscribed angle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle).

Comment: You should make $4$ equilateral triangles on $4$ sides and then area of intersection of the circumcircles of all those $4$ equilateral triangles is what you are seeking.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Hint:

If I understood correctly you mean the least measure of angle is $60^o$,that means it can be more; in this case , as can be seen in figure the area inside the boundary QRST is what you are looking for.The circle concentric with square is where four centers of circles locate. These circles pass two vertices of square and all points on curves opposite the related side of square is $60^o$.In figure:

measure of side is 100 (3 in your question). The measure of circles and also the distance from S to BC is given, Also the measure of arch RS is $60^o$. These values are enough for finding the area inside the boundary.

Comment: Many thanks for detailed explanation

Comment: You 're welcome.